# Why does this SQL query give correct results on my local database, but wrong result on the server database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, match, against

On my local MySQL database, this query to search for a specific word "samy" gives me the correct data consisting of two 2 results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM members

LEFT JOIN member_details
ON members.id_members = member_details.id_member

LEFT JOIN company_details
ON members.id_members = company_details.id_member

WHERE MATCH(name, lastname, email, phone, adress, 
  website, company_name, company_phone_01, 
  company_phone_02, company_fax, company_email, 
  company_description, company_adress, company_website) 
AGAINST("samy*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But when I run the same request on the server's mysql database, it returns all of the members data. It does however work when I do this:

```
WHERE MATCH(name, lastname, email, phone, adress, website) 
AGAINST("samy*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the data returned by the server?

Comment: Does your local dataset match the dataset on the server?

Comment: GustavBertram it's return all date like i did not any search. it's return all members list. http://www.vsook.com/members.php

Comment: richsage yes they are the same

Comment: Your local and production mysql servers the same version?

Comment: Local Mysql version is 5.1.36 And Mysql server is 5.0.92

Comment: Why on earth are you developing on a newer version than production? That's asking for trouble.

Comment: Well, it could be that the older MySQL version just has some limit on the number of fields in MATCH, or maybe it has a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Guess:  LocalDB is MyISAM, Production DB is InnoDB (which does not support full-text searches required by MATCH AGAINST)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that results in an error being raised, not the wrong data being returned.